# Capture Backslash in Javascript

Tags: jquery, regex

Am using Jquery validator to create a rule to disallow spl characters in fields.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpecialChar", function(value,element) {
    if(value.match(/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/)){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }, "No Special Charaters are allowed.");
```

the regular expression am using is not capturing "\" backslash.

can some one please help me on this?

Comment: Instead of excluding all special characters this way, you could just allow alphanumeric characters? `[0-9a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: add `\\\` to the regexp characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the backslash in the character class:

```
if(value.match(/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/\\]/))
```

But what about other "special characters" like `§`? The list is nearly endless - perhaps you would rather like to exclude *all* characters except for `A-Za-z0-9_`:

```
if (value.match(/\W/))
```

Comment: only a few set of spl characters are required to exclude... Thanks for the help.... :)

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` is the escape character so to include a literal backslash in a regular expression (or string) you must escape the backslash character itself, i.e. `\\`.

In your character class the single `\` is being used to escape the `]` to prevent it from being interpreted as the metacharacter which closes the character class.

The other `\` in your character class are unnecessary as the `]` is the only metacharacter that needs to be escaped within it.
`]`, `\`, `^` and `-` are the only characters that may need to be escaped in a character class.

As already mentioned, you may be better to specify what characters are disallowed by looking for characters that are not within a specified group, e.g.

```
/[^a-z\d\s]/i
```

which disallows any characters not `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or whitespace (the `\d` is short for `0-9` and the `i` means case-insensitive).

Also, in place of the `if-else` statement and `match`, you could simply use

```
return !value.test( /[^a-z\d\s]/i )
```

although you may find it less readable (the `!` inverts the boolean result of the `test` call).